# How to update BLOB column in Oracle which contains HTML code

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to update a BLOB column in Oracle DB with HTML. 
I am using Oracle Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0

The column contains HTML code which would be used in front end in JSP Servlets. The content of cell should be updated with below code

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td height="130">&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td height="130">&copy; 2013</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

The above code is formatted.The whole thing is single line.Now when I run a update query as below its showing the message

```
  UPDATE TemplateTbl
     SET TemplateConetent = (RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td height="130">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td height="130">&copy; 2013</td></tr></tbody></table>')))
   WHERE TemplateId = TL2600
```

Now oracle is asking for variable values because of © and   as below

[image]

I have tried using underscore, Backslash and percentage in front of &copy and &nbsp. But nothing worked. How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

1、sql  plus or plsql command window

```
set define off;

UPDATE TemplateTbl
     SET TemplateConetent = (RAWTOHEX (UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw ('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"><tbody><tr><td height="130">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td height="130">&copy; 2013</td></tr></tbody></table>')))
   WHERE TemplateId = TL2600
```

Comment: Thank you soo much for your reply.Its working.But in production server I cannot use set define off.

Comment: @JavaBeginner - Use `...="130">&'||'nbsp;</td>...` or `...="130">'||chr(38)||'nbsp;</td>...` to avoid magic of `&` symbol.

Answer (score 2):

HTML ist plain text, use an (N)CLOB for that.